# does we have coolant water in EGR?

Tags: egr

today i wanted to clean my EGR.

but when i disconnect below hose (picture) , coolant water splash out from there
[image]

is it okay this? why we have water in EGR?

Comment: Which car is the EGR valve off?  Where does the pipe go to?

Comment: The pipe go to head cylender.  I will check it for sure.  (I must remove the battery box)

Comment: Mazda 3 - 2008  2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is certainly not okay, but I doubt it's coolant.  It's probably condensation...

### ON EDIT:

HandyHowie and the OP (Mostafa) are indeed correct.  Now that I know what vehicle we are speaking of, I went to AllData and found this:

[image: 2008 Mazda 3 2.0 EGR]

It is coolant, and for exactly the reason Howie suggested.  EGR reduces combustion temperature with a "cool" non-combustible gas (exhaust), which leads to lower NOX emissions as well as the ability to increase timing advance without damage.  In some vehicles, ostensibly this exhaust gas is cooled even further with engine coolant.

I done learnt something.

So, the good news is that it is exactly as it should be, and there may be some residual coolant if the hose is removed.

Comment: Are you saying that from experience with this EGR valve?  It would appear to me that this pipe is intended to keep the EGR valve cool.  If it is indeed an EGR valve.

Comment: @steveraceri think you wrong?https://forums.edmunds.com/discussion/43437/mitsubishi/galant/should-my-egr-valve-lines-have-coolant-in-them